# How to transport ToggleButton to SecondActivity

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I've got a problem. I need to transport my `TooggleButton` to `SecondActivity` with saved state and I completely don't know how to do it.
I've got something like this if `MainActivity`:

```
public void changeButton(View view)
{
    boolean on = ((ToggleButton) view).isChecked();

    if(on)
    {
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(59, 223, 59));
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Basket.class);
        intent.putExtra(Basket.TOGGLE_ON_EXTRA, getToggleState());
        startActivity(intent);

    }
    else
    {
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255, 100, 100));
    }
}
```

and SecondActivity

```
public class Basket extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_basket);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    boolean toggleOn = intent.getBooleanExtra(TOGGLE_ON_EXTRA, false);
}
```

Seriously only this part works fine

```
 public void changeButton(View view)
{
    boolean on = ((ToggleButton) view).isChecked();

    if(on)
    {
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(59, 223, 59));

    }
    else
    {
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255, 100, 100));
    }
}
```

In first example, problems are `TOGGLE_ON_EXTRA` and `getToggleState()`.

Comment: What does getToggleState() return? Also, you only invoke the Basket Activity when the ToggleButton is on, so you already now isChecked() to be true?

Comment: It return nothing, can't be used, becouse I didn't declare it before (I just found it in the internet). Only third part of code works (only changing color).

Answer (score 0):

When starting the next activity use put extra.

```
startActivity(new Intent(Main.this, ActivitySecond.class).putExtra("state","on");
```

And in the second activity get the extra information like this:

```
String state = getIntent().getExtras().getString("state");
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this only open SecondActivity without making there the same ToggleButton :(

Comment: You simply need to have a ToggleButton in the layout xml of R.layout.activity_basket and set the value based on the received intent. The same could be done for the rgb values if that is needed as well.

Comment: It doesn't work. But it's not even what I wan't to get. I need to make it like in online shop, you know... if something is chosen it makes in a basket (and you can still throw it out of it)

Comment: @calvinklein Then you need a database or similar to store the information and create the button based on that information, e.g. have the user selected any items. This changes your question from how to pass the state of a button into how to store and retrieve data. To mention some options http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html and http://parse.com